# Responsive Design without bootstrap

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm having a bit of a design issue with a website I'm trying to build in that I can't get it to be responsive to the different screen resolutions.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.menubar {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 150;
}

#logo {
  width: 550px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: 40%;
}

.menubar ul,
li,
a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.menubar a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.menubar.two a {
  color: black;
}

.slider-contain {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}

.a-slide {
  background-size: cover !important;
}

.slick-slider {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.slick-list,
.slick-track {
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 101;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.overlay p {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: auto;
  top: 85%;
  font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}

.overlay h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  top: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}

.brand-wrap {
  border-bottom: 1px black solid;
}

.item {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.slick-slidertwo {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay-about {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 101;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: white;
}

.wrap-about {
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 175px;
  padding-left: 65px;
}

.overlay-about p {
  line-height: 27px;
  width: 700px;
}

.overlay-about h1 {
  color: goldenrod;
}

#about {
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.wrap-service {
  padding-top: 95px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.services h1 {
  color: goldenrod;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.services p {
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  width: 52%
}

#s1 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 10px 16px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.41);
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 10px 16px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.41);
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 16px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.41);
}

#underline {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.service-images {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.service-items {
  width: 63%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -43px;
}

.wrap-service h1 {
  font-size: 55px;
  color: goldenrod;
}

.empty {
  height: 100px;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-top: lightgrey 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

#googleMap {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
}

.contact-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.contact {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 19.8%;
  float: right;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
}

.menubar.two {}

.contact p {
  line-height: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
}


/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
}


/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
}


/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
}


/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
}


/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
}


/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
}


/* Large screens ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1824px) {
  /* Styles */
}


/* iPhone 4 ----------- */

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>R&R Cycle: Motorcycle and ATV Service Center</title>
  <!-- Main CSS + Slick Slider CSS Files -->
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick/slick.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick/slick-theme.css" />
  <!-- Google Fonts, FontAwesome, Favicon, Crawler JS for brands scroll -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon-motorcycle.ico" />
  <script src="js/crawler.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fa/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- AOS for scroll animations -->
  <script src="aos-master/dist/aos.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="aos-master/dist/aos.css" /> </head>

<body>
  <!-- Start Menu -->
  <div class="menubar">
    <a href="#" class="logo"></a>
    <ul class="mainmenu">
      <li><a style="color:goldenrod;" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Part Catalogs</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact">Contact / Hours</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- Splash Page Slider + Overlay info -->
  <div class="slider-contain">
    <div class="overlay">
      <img id="logo" align="right" src="img/R&R.png" alt="">
      <p>Service and Repair for All Makes and Models Since 1979!</p>
      <h2>Call Us Today: 845-336-5910</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="slick-slider">
      <div class="a-slide" style="background: url('img/slider-4.jpeg') no-repeat center center"></div>
      <div class="a-slide" style="background: url('img/slider-2.jpeg') no-repeat center center"></div>
      <div class="a-slide" style="background: url('img/slider-3.jpeg') no-repeat center center"></div>
      <div class="a-slide" style="background: url('img/slider-5.jpg') no-repeat center center"></div>
      <div class="a-slide" style="background: url('img/sunset-summer-motorcycle.jpg') no-repeat center center"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Brands slider w/ Crawler JS -->
  <br />
  <div class="brand-wrap">
    <div id="brands"> <img id="banner" src="img/banner.jpg" /> </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Brand Slider -->
  <!-- About Us Slider + Info -->
  <div class="slider-contain">
    <div class="overlay-about">
      <a id="about"></a>
      <div class="wrap-about">
        <h1>About "The Shop"</h1>
        <p data-aos="fade-up">We are nestled in the scenic Catskill mountains in the Hudson River Valley, home to some of the best riding areas in the northeast. Situated about 2 hrs. north of New York City and just a few miles from I-87 (New York State Thru-Way) exit 19,
          Kingston. R&R Cycle was started in 1979 by brothers Frank Rua & Henry Rua.
          <br/>
          <br /> As in many small businesses, it was launched out of the passion and enjoyment of the sport, along with the frustration with impersonal, overpriced corporate dealership attitude. With Frank's technical skills from his AMI (American Motorcycle
          Institute) certification and Henry's business knowledge, R&R Cycle was born. In 1985 Steve Mulford joined our shop family. Steve also attended and became certified at AMI in Daytona Beach, Florida. He has a vast acquired knowledge of motorcycles
          and ATVs. With almost 30 years of experience in real world shop situations, he has no equal in our area. Frank and Steve are both lifetime career mechanics, enthusiasts, and advocates for safe and responsible riding. We continue after almost
          40 years to be small enough and personal, but yet large enough to attend to all your powersports needs. We have acquired a huge network of suppliers, vendors, and salvage yards all over the USA for hard to find items and parts. If you are in
          our area please stop bye and say, Hi.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slick-slidertwo">
      <div class="a-slide" style="background: url('img/a1.JPG') no-repeat center center"></div>
      <div class="a-slide" style="background: url('img/a2.JPG') no-repeat center center"></div>
      <div class="a-slide" style="background: url('img/a3.JPG') no-repeat center center"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End About Us -->
  <!-- AOS: http://michalsnik.github.io/aos/ -->
  <div class="wrap-service">
    <a id="services"></a>
    <div class="services">
      <h1 style="font-size:45px;">A Business Built On Service.</h1>
      <div class="service-images">
        <div id="s1" class="slick-serviceone">
          <div class="a-slide" style="background: url('img/s1.JPG') no-repeat center center"></div>
          <div class="a-slide" style="background: url('img/s2.JPG') no-repeat center center"></div>
          <div class="a-slide" style="background: url('img/s3.JPG') no-repeat center center"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p data-aos="fade-up"> Our Business is built on service. Together, Frank and Steve have over 50 years of real world shop experience. They are both AMI (American Motorcycle Institute) Certified mechanics. We have been in the same location for over 30 years. Our goal is
        to get the job done right the first time. Listening and understanding our customers and their needs is essential to achieving this goal.
        <br />
        <br />In addition to the usual tune ups, we sell and install hundreds of top name brand tires each season with state of the art mounting and computer tire balancing equipment. We are second to none for carburetor and electrical troubleshooting,
        diagnosis, repair. Our new Ultrasonic carb cleaning tank does a great job. Complex electrical charging & ignition systems on modern units require accurate testing before expensive components are purchased. Whether its motorcycles or ATV's. </p>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <hr id="underline">
    <div class="service-items">
      <div class="item" data-aos="flip-up"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Complete engine overhauls- top end - bottom end</div>
      <div class="item" data-aos="flip-up"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Transmission rebuilds - shift forks - gears - etc...</div>
      <div class="item" data-aos="flip-up"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Wheel lacing & truing</div>
      <div class="item" data-aos="flip-up"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Crankshaft rebuilding </div>
      <div class="item" data-aos="flip-up"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Fork tube straightening </div>
      <div class="item" data-aos="flip-up"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cylinder boring/honing </div>
      <div class="item" data-aos="flip-up"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Valve reconditioning </div>
      <div class="item" data-aos="flip-up"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Front end alignment </div>
      <div class="item" data-aos="flip-up"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Accident damage </div>
      <div class="item" data-aos="flip-up"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pre Purchase appraisal of used cycles / ATV's </div>
      <div class="item" data-aos="flip-up"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pick Up & Delivery Available </div>
      <div class="item" data-aos="flip-up"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Custom fabrication- lighting,wheels,fenders,exhaust, etc...</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Temp Break to see animation for all items -->
  </div>
  <div class="empty"></div>
  <!-- Footer for Copyright and stuff like that, a little fame for me... -->
  <div class="footer">

    <p style="color:grey;">© 2017 R&R Cycle Inc. | Designed By Frank Rua. | frankselectronicmail@gmail.com</p>
  </div>
  <!-- End footer -->
  <!-- --------------------------<Scripts>---------------------------------- -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/slideshow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/smoothscroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/banner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/aso.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I pulled the media queries from another site to speed that process up, but I've tried a couple different methods to transform my CSS and nothing is working. Including making my Text "Divs" smaller when the screen gets smaller but all that does is cut off the text more because the location changes. This is the last solution I tried was just transforming the body of the page using:

```
  left: x%;
  transform: translate(-x%, -x);
  top: x%;
```

Which gave me no progress just a page that was split by a certain percentage. I've been reading articles on how to do this and I just can't get a grasp on it ;Responsive design is something I'm fairly new to and I'm not exactly sure how to transform this. Can somebody give me an example with this webpage so I can see?

Here's a Screenfly so you can see what I'm talking about, the text under "The Shop" is cut off.
[Screenfly Example](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//rrcycleinc.com&w=1024&h=600&a=1&s=1)

I know it's easy to downvote a question like this, but I'd rather have someboyd give me a real life example with the webpage I'm working with and then an explanation not a generic example taken off the internet, which is what I'm struggling with at the moment. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your media queries will not work, cause you not put any css selector to apply styles to. Please look this [simple media queries example](http://jsfiddle.net/DrSRT/).

```
p{
    font-family: arial,san-serif;   
    font-size: 13px;
    font-color: black;
}

h1{
    font-size:30px;   
}

@media screen and (min-width:761px){
    body{
        background-color:white;
    }
    h1{
        color:red;
    }    
}

@media screen and (max-width:760px){
    body{
        background-color: #333;
    }
    h1{
        color:red;
    }  
    p{
        color: white;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px){
    body{
        background-color: #807f83;
    }
    h1{
        color:white;
    }  
    p{
        color: white;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:360px){
    body{
        background-color: #0096d6;
    }
    h1{
        color:white;
        font-size:25px;
    }  
    p{
        color: white;
    }
}
```

In media queries you should add css selector and then style rules to apply